# How to define a new type (class) in Python using C API?

Tags: python, c, class

I am trying to use the Python C API to define a new class inside a module that would expose certain functionality written in C to Python code. I specifically want to have it in the form of a class and not a set of module functions.

However, I can't find anything regarding this particular task in the official documentation. The closest I could find is PyClass_New function (in the Python.h header) but it is not mentioned anywhere in the official docs, so I assume it is not supposed to be used.

So, what is the proper way to define a new Python class from C code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

[This part](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html) of the docs (and surrounding ones) should give you most of the info you need.  The [xxsubtype.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/xxsubtype.c) sources provide one example module that defines a new class (as a subclass of `list`, to show precisely how to do that, too) and [xxmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/xxmodule.c) shows (among many other things) also how to define a new type.

Answer (score -4):

```
 static PyObject* Request_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
```

May help you, then you can declare `PyTypeObject` variable to define a new class.

Comment: Please explain your answer!